# How to match a struct instantiation with macro_rules

Tags: rust, macros, macro-rules

Since this took  me a while to figure out, I may as well share how I fixed it.

I was trying to wrap every item on a struct with some function, in my case `Arc::new(Mutex::new(item))` with `macro_rules`

My initial attempt was many variations on this:

```rust
macro_rules! decl_sr {
    (
        $name:ident {
            $( $it:ident : $value:expr) ,*
        }
    ) => {
        $name {
            $( $it: Arc::new(Mutex::new( $value )) ),*
        }
    };
}
```

And the idea was to use it like this:

```rust
let mut value = decl_sr!{
    StructName {
        field_1: Value1::from_function_call(parameter1, parameter2),
        // -- snip
        field_n: ValueN::from_function_call(parameter1, parameter2),
    }
}
```

So it actually resulted in this:

```rust
let mut value = decl_sr!{
    StructName {
        field_1: Arc::new(Mutex::new(Value1::from_function_call(parameter1, parameter2))),
        // -- snip
        field_n: Arc::new(Mutex::new(ValueN::from_function_call(parameter1, parameter2))),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer was this:

```rust
    macro_rules! decl_sr {
        (
            $name:ident {
                $( $it:ident : $value:expr, )*
            }
        ) => {
            $name {
                $( $it: Arc::new(Mutex::new( $value )) ),*
            }
        };
```

With the comma (',') **inside** the repetition pattern.

Otherwise it would throw the classic macro error `no rules expected token '}'`. `-Z macro-backtrace` and `trace_macros!(true);` didn't help at all.

The only thing that tipped me off was [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211450/writing-a-rust-macro-repetition-that-may-or-may-not-initialize-a-struct-field), but it wasn't exactly about this.

I may have picked too loose/bad fragment specifiers, feel free to correct me/suggest better options in the comments. Most of the time trying to make this works was thinking *they were the problem*, not the comma so I was glad it worked at all.